# Ktor - checking passwords against wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to perform user authentication against a wordpress/Mysql database in ktor. As far as I know, passwords are stored in the wp_users table after a hashing transformation, performed with [phpass](https://www.openwall.com/phpass/) framework.
Starting from a plain text password, my aim is to compare this password with the hash stored in the database, to understand if I have to authenticate the user or not.
Is there any support between ktor and mysql/wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it!
I found out from the documentation that wordpress uses a password hashing function called [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Then I searched github for a java implementation and I got into this [repository](https://github.com/Wolf480pl/PHPass/tree/master/phpass/src/com/github/wolf480pl/phpass) by Wolf480pl.
By copying `BCrypt.java` and `PHPass.java` files into my project, I just wrote this simple kotlin function to check the match between the hash stored into the database (I used Exposed to connect to the mySQL db) and the plain text password:

```kotlin
fun passwordMatch(password: String, storedHash: String): Boolean {
    val checker = PHPass(8)
    return checker.checkPassword(password, storedHash)
}
```

Just that, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Ktor itself knows nothing about Wordpress or any other PHP techonology.
Actually, it doesn't know about databases either. There is an [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) ORM-framework, which is often used in Ktor projects for that. It supports MySQL databases, so it will be suitable in this case too.

But I believe you will have to write this integration by yourself, cause this is a rather exotic combination of technologies (Ktor+Wordpress), and highly unlikely someone else did it before.